# Switching from resource-based binding to design time binding kills IError based validation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm working on a code base which appears to be using design time data binding during runtime. The XAML files generally follow this kind of pattern:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="TheNamespace.TheView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:TheNamespace="clr-namespace:TheNamespace"
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=TheNamespace:TheViewModel}"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="750" d:DesignWidth="1000">
```

Later on, when defining a binding, the source file might look like this:

```xml
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Title}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=Enabled}" />
```

As far as I can tell no other additional resources are loaded.

In order to implement some data validation on the app, I concocted my own MWE which I believe replicates how the XAML is put together:

```xml
<Window x:Class="validate_on_data_errors.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:validate_on_data_errors="clr-namespace:validate_on_data_errors"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=validate_on_data_errors:PersonImplementsIDataErrorInfo}"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel Margin="20">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <validate_on_data_errors:PersonImplementsIDataErrorInfo x:Key="data"/>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        
        <TextBlock>Enter your age:</TextBlock>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding 
                Path=Age, 
                Source={StaticResource data},
                ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,
                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            </TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

This is loosely based on the example in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.validatesondataerrors?view=windowsdesktop-6.0). I'm using the exact same code for `PersonImplementsIDataErrorInfo.cs`.

When I try to remove the `StackPanel.Resource` altogether and simply replicate how things are done in the main codebase, I lose the data validation:

```xml
<Window x:Class="validate_on_data_errors.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:validate_on_data_errors="clr-namespace:validate_on_data_errors"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=validate_on_data_errors:PersonImplementsIDataErrorInfo}"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel Margin="20">
        
        <TextBlock>Enter your age:</TextBlock>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding 
                Path=Age, 
                ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,
                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            </TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

This is confusing to me because the codebase implements data validation using `ValidatesOnDataErrors` and `IError` using only design time data binding.

Why won't it work on my simple example?

Comment: There is nothing like "*design time data binding during runtime*". You certainly overlooked some code behind where the actual DataContext was set.

Comment: I've double checked and there is no `DataContext` being set in the code-behind. Where else could it be?

Comment: If you are looking at the code of a UserControl, there should not be any explicit DataContext assignment, because UserControls are not supposed to do that. For a top-level element like a Window or Page, there should be an assignment either in XAML or code behind, typically in the view's constructor like `DataContext = new ViewModel();`. IMO, learning WPF from only looking at documentation examples  is not a good approach. Better start with a book like for example *WPF Unleashed* by Adam Nathan.

Comment: @Clemens I think you're right. That `UserControl` is being imported by yet another `UserControl` for which the code-behind explicitly assigns the datacontext in its constructor....

I looked into *WPF Unleashed* but I'm a bit concerned that it might be out of date...

Comment: Out of data for learning the basics? Not at all...